# Windows 10 Pro computer locks out user after a minute of idle time regardless of the settings

Tags: login, desktop, lock-screen

I have a Windows 10  Pro (version 10.0.17134) computer that is part of our domain, that after a minute of idle time locks the user out.

It is not a group policy issue, and we already looked at the power-saving and screen setting. Does anyone know what might be causing this?

Comment: This only happens at idle? If the computer is active it will not lock? Also, what is the desired behavior?

Comment: Yes if the user is working on it wont lock, if she gets up or is reading something on the screen and don't move the mouse. it locks

Answer (score 0):

Some power options are hidden. To set them, it may be necessary to change power button options.

- Press <kbd>Windows</kbd>, type `buttons` and select `Change what the power buttons do`.
  [image: Power Options\System Settings]
- In the `Power Options\System Settings` dialog, select `Change settings that are currently unavailable`.
- Enable all `Shutdown Settings`.
- Click on `Power Options` in the address bar.
- Check the `Sleep` options of the current power plan to see if a previously-hidden setting is revealed with a short timeout.